# Configuring routes with polymorphic associations in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails app I have user, school, and course models.  I have set up a polymorphic association so that users and schools have many courses as hostable, and the course belongs_to hostable.  My routes look like this:

```
  resources :users do
    resources :courses
  end

 resources :schools do
   resources :courses 
 end
```

The show in my school controller looks like this:

```
def show
  @school = School.find(params[:id])
  @user = current_user.schools.find_by_user_id(params[:user_id])
  @title = @school.school_name
  @hostable = @school
  @courses = @hostable.courses
  @course = Course.new
end
```

The courses partial that renders in the school and user show page looks like this:

```
<div id="courses">
 <% @courses.each do |course| %>
  <div class="course">
<%= simple_format course.title %>
    <%= simple_format course.description %>
  </div>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

Right now I only have the school view configured to simply list the course title and description.  What I want to do is list all of the school's courses on the school's show page, and instead of only showing the text of the course title, I want the course title to be a link which re-directs to the course's page.  Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Not directly related, but im wondering why you used a polymorphic relation here? IMHO two seperate relations, one to school, and one to user makes more sense here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= link_to course.title, school_course_path(@hostable, course) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have defined a route in `config/routes.rb` to be able to link to the nested resource this way. This will give you the route if you don't already have it:

```
resources :schools do
  resources :courses
end
```

You can run `rake routes` to get a list of all of your routes. In my example you would get a `school_courses` listing. You can then make a `link_to course.title, school_courses_path(@hostable, course)` as Wawa Loo pointed out.