# Comments on multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, crud

Within my rails app, I currently have comments setup to work with my posts model, which is functioning properly. How do I add comments to my books model?

Here is what I have so far:

Here is what I have in my schema for the comments:

```
 create_table "comments", force: true do |t|
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "post_id"
    t.integer  "book_id"
  end
```

In my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  acts_as_voter
end
```

In my post model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end
```

In my book model:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end
```

In my comment model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :user
  acts_as_votable
end
```

In my comments controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    post.comments.create(new_comment_params) do |comment|
      comment.user = current_user
    end
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to post_path(post)}
    end
  end


  def upvote
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
  @comment.liked_by current_user

  respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to @post}
    end
end


  private

  def new_comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
  end

  def post
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  end

end
```

In my routes file:

```
resources :posts do
    resources :comments do
    member do
      put "like", to: "comments#upvote"
    end
  end
  end
```

In my view:

```
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= comment.body  %>

  <% if user_signed_in? && (current_user != comment.user) && !(current_user.voted_for? comment) %>

<%= link_to “up vote”, like_post_comment_path(@post, comment), method: :put %>

<%= comment.votes.size %>

<% else %>

<%= comment.votes.size  %></a>

<% end %>
<% end %>


<br />


<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>

  <p><%= f.text_area :body, :cols => "80", :rows => "10" %></p>

  <p><%= f.submit “comment” %></p>

<% end %>
```

What do I add to my comments controller to get comments working on both posts and books? What do I add to my routes file?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Try to follow this simple example: http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association

Comment: Thank you for the helpfulness and not being a snark-ish prick like some of the people on here!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't want to specify each type of object that can hold `Comment` objects.  That creates a headache of `if-elsif-else` blocks all over the place.  Instead, you want things to be `Commentable`, and they all will have `.comments` on them.

This is called a [polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) in Active Record.  So you would have your models something like:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end
```

And modify your database accordingly, it's all in the linked article.  Now when you build a `Comment` object for a form, it will have pre-populated a `commentable_id` and `commentable_type`, which you can toss in hidden fields.  Now it doesn't matter what the `Comment` is associated with, you always treat it the same.

I'd leave `User` as a separate association, since it's not really the same idea.

Comment: For my comments table, should I remove post_id and book_id and add commentable_id:integer commentable_type:string ? Can I still keep use_id?

Comment: Can I use the controller code in this tutorial? http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association

Comment: For the routes, can I use the code in this tutorial? How do I add upvotes to the comments in the routes?

Comment: Controller code looks fine in that article.  As for the routes, that looks a little dated.  You can use the same `resources` routing you had before, but you may want to point them at a common controller, depending on what you're doing.  The [Rails routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) tutorial covers lots of options.  As for upvotes, it looks like you're on the right track with the `upvote` controller method and using `acts_as_votable`.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I'm getting this error in my posts show view: undefined method `comments_path  , I dont have a comments_path, I do have a post_comments_path, and a book_comments_path, how do I get the form to use these?

Comment: Run `rake routes` to see the routes available to you.  You could try `polymorphic_path`, not sure if that will help you depending on your situation.  There's also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298872/configuring-routes-with-polymorphic-associations-in-rails) about polymorphic associations and routes.  Questions more specific like this may be better off as a whole new StackOverflow question.

Comment: K, thanks Nick, you've been super helpful so far, I think I'll post this in a separate question.