# Polymorphic comments route error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Take a look at this question I just asked: [Comments on multiple models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22025288/comments-on-multiple-models)

So far I have everything setup correctly, my comments table, my models and controllers.

But, i'm running into some route error.

In my routes file:

```
resources :posts do
    resources :comments do
    member do
      put "like", to: "comments#upvote"
    end
  end

  end

  resources :books do
    resources :comments do
    member do
      put "like", to: "comments#upvote"
    end
  end

  end
```

My comments form:

```
<% form_for [@commentable, Comment.new] do |f| %>
  <p>
   <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>
```

This is the error i'm getting:

undefined method `comments_path'

Any idea on how to get the routes working?

Edit:

This is what I have in my comments controller:

```
def index
  @commentable = find_commentable
  @comments = @commentable.comments
end

def create
  @commentable = find_commentable
  @comment = @commentable.comments.build(params[:comment])
  if @comment.save
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully created comment."
    redirect_to :id => nil
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end

private

def find_commentable
  params.each do |name, value|
    if name =~ /(.+)_id$/
      return $1.classify.constantize.find(value)
    end
  end
  nil
end
```

Comment: What is the `@commentable` variable?

Comment: Just added an edit to the question showing what I have in my controller

Comment: Are you sure that `@commentable` is defined in whatever controller action is rendering the initial comment form?

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm a bit confused. I'm supposed to define @commentable within my posts and books controllers or comments controller? What do I define it as? The polymorphic comments are really confusing me.

Comment: what url are you accessing when getting the error?

Comment: I'm trying to access my posts show view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Katie, `@commentable` should be loaded for every action on which you are rendering the comment form. I think you are forgoing `comments#new` in favor of using `books#show` or `posts#show` to render the form (which is fine), but that variable needs to be loaded every time you want to render the form.

However, since defining a `@commentable` variable in `books#show` isn't very expressive (you probably already have a `@book` defined), here's what I would suggest:

Create a new partial (if you don't have one already) for the comment form:

```
<% form_for [commentable, Comment.new] do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Notice `commentable` is not an instance variable here. When you render the partial, you will define it as a local variable. Somewhere in `books/show.html.erb`:

```
 <%= render partial: "comments/form", locals: { commentable: @book } %>
```

Obviously, in other views, replace `@book` with whatever variable should be `commentable`.

Now you'll have another issue, which is that the form data won't carry the `commentable_type` and `commentable_id` attributes. There are a number of ways you can get them into your `CommentsController`; here's a simple one using hidden fields:

```
<% form_for [commentable, Comment.new] do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :commentable_type, commentable.class.to_s %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :commentable_id, commentable.id %>
  <p>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>
```

You'll need to change the `find_commentable` action to something a bit more simple:

```
def find_commentable
  params[:commentable_type].constantize.find(params[:commentable_id])
end
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much! I must be doing something wrong, i'm not getting errors within my books show view, but the form just isnt rendering at all, can we continue this in the chat box thingy if you have time?

Comment: Sure: [http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/48418/question22027185](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/48418/question22027185?tab=general)

Answer (score 1):

If you are rendering the comment form under the `PostsController#show` action, then you want to make sure that `@commentable` is defined within that action somewhere.

```
# PostsController#show
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @commentable = @post
end
```

That way, the use of `@commentable` in the `form_for [@commentable, Comment.new]` call is defined.